# Is it possible to import a keyring to another from its binary files

Tags: keyrings, gnome-keyring

I have recently set up a computer (using Precise), and want to import data I have saved from another Ubuntu (Maverick). These data include a gnome keyring, which I (rather stupidly) copied the encrypted files instead of exporting.

```
What I did > cp -R ~/.gnome2/keyring /backup/gnome2_keyring
```

Given that I still know the session passwords I used for the corresponding user account on old Maverick computer, what can I do to recover/import passwords ?

As this is a home user question, and has to be done only once, I am not concerned with security problems: I'll wipe my free space afterwards and that will be enough.

Comment: since this question is answered [at superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/508916/is-it-possible-to-import-a-gnome-keyring-to-another-from-its-binary-files), i think you should mark this as solved. And your question helped me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked the same question on superUser: https://superuser.com/questions/508916/is-it-possible-to-import-a-gnome-keyring-to-another-from-its-binary-files

In short, the answer is: for a recent enough version of seahorse, just copying the directory will work